# Updating an array in a discriminated model in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a model called `Person` which has a discriminator of `"Worker"` which gives it an additional `locations` field of an array.

I am trying to push an element onto the locations array without going through the fetch/modify/save method (so I can use `updateMany` later on to update several documents at the same time).

Why is that not happening in the code below? I have tried this with `findByIdAndUpdate` and `findOneAndUpdate` as well.

`index.js`:

```
const { connect } = require("mongoose");

const Person = require("./Person");

connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/test?gssapiServiceName=mongodb", {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
}, async () => {
  console.log("Database connected")
  const person = await Person.create(
    {
      __t: "Worker",
      name: "John", 
      locations: ["America"],
    },
  )

  console.log(person);
  // Outputs: 
  // {
  //   locations: [ 'America' ],
  //   _id: 5eba279663ecdbc25d4d73d4,
  //   __t: 'Worker',
  //   name: 'John',
  //   __v: 0
  // }

  await Person.updateOne(
    { _id: person._id }
    {
      $push: { locations: "UK" }, 
    },
  )

  const updated = await Person.findById(person._id);

  console.log(updated);
  // (Updating "locations" was unsuccessful)
  // Outputs: 
  // {
  //   locations: [ 'America' ],
  //   __t: 'Worker',
  //   _id: 5eba279663ecdbc25d4d73d4,
  //   name: 'John',
  //   __v: 0
  // }
});
```

`Person.js`:

```
const { Schema, model } = require("mongoose");

const personSchema = Schema({
  name: String,
});

const Person = model("Person", personSchema);

Person.discriminator(
  "Worker",
  Schema({
    locations: [String],
  })
);

module.exports = Person;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out you have to pass in the key (`__t`) when updating from the root `Parent` model and not the `Worker` model as the database does not know what fields a `Worker` would have.

Therefore, you can do the following:

```
await Person.updateOne(
  { _id : person._id, __t: "Worker" },
  { $push: { locations: "UK" } }
)
```

See more in [this Github issue](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/8982)